# Downgrade SQL Server engine to Express edition on Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, downgrade

By mistake I have provisioned a SQL Server Web edition for our Elastic Beanstalk environment. Can I shomehow downgrade this to the SQL Server express edition? Alternatively I guess we could set up an entirely new Elastic Beanstalk environment?

I would prefer not to have to provision a completely new environment since we now have white listed the IP adresses for the existing environment and would like to avoid having to whitelist a new environment (I foresee a new version would come with a new IP adress).

It would be OK for us if we can just close down the DB server part of the EB environment and then change the DB engine from web to express, but I could not find any article on how to do that :-(

The closest being an article about how to upgrade from older versions of the SQL Server database: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.SQLServer.html

Thanks for any help!

-Claus

Comment: The concept of PAAS is different in Azure,than AWS.I *think*  you must start by procuring new instance or else contact support

Answer (score -1):

With SQL Server, there is no concept of downgrading editions. The only way to accomplish what you are asking is to uninstall the SQL portion of the server and then install SQL Express edition. Make sure you look at the limitations of Express edition before you do this as you could be worse off than when you started.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. The question is about *Amazon* and managed instances. Downgrading *is* possible. The question is how - can it be done through the portal, or should the OP call support?

Comment: Apologies, i understood this as a SQL Server question. In which case, you cannot downgrade editions once it is installed. You have to uninstall and then install over again.